# ASP.NET MVC jQuery Ajax - close and refresh parent table from modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Very new to both MVC and jQuery, so I'm not sure how to get this to work. I've cobbled together a (somewhat) working modal dialog form with an ajax postback. Been searching for two days and not finding great MVC+jQuery examples out there. The data gets inserted as expected, it's just the UI I'm having a hard time with.

I've got two views: Index and Create. Index lists all records inside a plain table, looping the results with Razor. Create is the insert form which I'm loading into a modal dialog:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.StockIndex>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin: Stock Index Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>View Stock Indices</h2>

<p>
    <a href="#" id="createLink">Create New</a>
    <div id="createStockIndexForm"></div>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('#createLink').on('click', function () {
            $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
                width: 600,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Create Stock Index',
                modal: true,
                open: function () {
                    $(this).load('@Url.Action("Create", "AdminStockIndex")');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller actions:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new StockIndexEditViewModel()
        {
            StockIndices = GetIndices()
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(StockIndexEditViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

The "Create" form that was loaded into the dialog (above):

```
@model MyProject.Models.StockIndexEditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreatePartial";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>CreatePartial</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdminStockIndex", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="result"></div>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>StockIndexEditViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedParentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedParentId, Model.StockIndices, "- Select One -", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" id="createButton" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#createForm").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                async: true,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        var createForm = $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog();
                        createForm.dialog("close");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#result").append("Something went fail.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The modal dialog always goes blank, rather than closing. In testing in Firefox using Firebug, I occasionally see this error, but not every time:

> InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by
>   the underlying object

Upon searching, I see that it's a CORS problem where FF is enforcing the rules and other browsers may not be. It's frustrating that the error doesn't always occur - appears to be random. Behaves the same in Chrome but doesn't ever throw an error in the JS console.

Firstly, how would I pull this off? Secondly, is there a way to refresh the table on the parent page via ajax, without plugins?

**UPDATE:**

With Eckert's help, I've made a little progress.

I'm trying to avoid the MVC Ajax helpers and sticking with a "pure" jQuery approach. I replaced the list of records on Index with a div, which contains a PartialView:

```
<div id="stockIndices">
    @Html.Partial("_StockIndices", Model)
</div>
```

I've got the underlying table refresh working by reloading the div with the close property of the jQuery dialog:

```
    $('#createLink').on('click', function () {
        $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            position: { my: "center", at: "top+400", of: window },
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Create Stock Index',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("Create", "AdminStockIndex")');
            },
            close: function () {
                $("#stockIndices").load('@Url.Action("GetStockIndices", "AdminStockIndex")');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Upon closing the modal dialog manually, the div reloads just how I wanted. Great! Now if I could get the dialog to close when the form posts, I'd be set. This does not work:

```
$("#createStockIndexForm").dialog("close");
```

Firebug reports the error:

> Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'close'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get everything I wanted, while retaining the "pure" jQuery Ajax approach, instead of resorting to the MVC Ajax helpers, suggested by Eckert. His suggestions lead me to the solution, however. Big thanks!

I created a PartialView in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetStockIndices()
    {
        _service = new StockIndexService();
        var data = _service.GetAll();

        return PartialView("_StockIndices", data);
    }
```

...and its view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.StockIndex>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Then I changed the modal dialog script to load the partial view when closed. Here's the entire Index view, for posterity:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.StockIndex>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin: Stock Index Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>View Stock Indices</h2>

<p>
    <a href="#" id="createLink">Create New</a>
    <div id="createStockIndexForm"></div>
</p>
<div id="stockIndices">
    @Html.Partial("_StockIndices", Model)
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var _dialog;

        $('#createLink').on('click', function () {
            _dialog = $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                position: { my: "center", at: "top+400", of: window },
                width: 600,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Create Stock Index',
                modal: true,
                open: function () {
                    $(this).load('@Url.Action("Create", "AdminStockIndex")');
                },
                close: function () {
                    $("#stockIndices").load('@Url.Action("GetStockIndices", "AdminStockIndex")');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Notice the global "_dialog" variable. This gave me access to the dialog from the Create form, so it could be closed:

```
<script>
    $("#createForm").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            async: true,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    if (_dialog) {
                        _dialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("#result").append("Error! Record could not be added.");
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The modal dialog always goes blank, rather than closing.

It's probably behaving improperly because you're creating a variable based on the dialog method of an object, and not the object itself.  Try this instead:

```
if (data) {
  $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog("close");
}
```

> Secondly, is there a way to refresh the table on the parent page via
>   ajax, without plugins?

There sure is, but it may require you to change some things, including the code to close your dialog.  Here's how I would handle it:

1) your table of records should be a partial view within the main Index view.  The reason for this is because when we submit your form, we'll use the ajax-option "InsertionMode" coupled with the target-id to replace your old records table with the updated one from the form.

2) rather than handling your dialog-close code in the on-submit method, we'll instead use the ajax-option "OnSuccess" to do that (and also "OnFailure" to handle your 'Something went fail' error).

So here's your new Index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.StockIndex>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Admin: Stock Index Home";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>View Stock Indices</h2>

<p>
  <a href="#" id="createLink">Create New</a>
  <div id="createStockIndexForm"></div>
</p>

<div id="recordsDiv">
  @Html.Partial("RecordsPartial", model)
</div>

// all your script stuff can still go at the end
```

Most of the Index view is unchanged, with the exception that we're now using a  that contains a partial view.  This partial view will include the table of records, coded here:

Create a new partial view named "RecordsPartial":

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.StockIndex>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now your "Create" view will be updated to use the mvc-ajax helper rather than use all that additional javascript code:

```
@model MyProject.Models.StockIndexEditViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreatePartial";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>CreatePartial</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateRecord", "AdminStockIndex", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "recordsDiv", OnSuccess = "postSuccess", OnFailure = "postFailed" })
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div id="result"></div>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <h4>StockIndexEditViewModel</h4>
      <hr />
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

      /* form fields here */

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
          <input type="submit" value="Create" id="createButton" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
}
```

We changed your form to be ajax-post, and we've added ajax-options to handle what happens after your form has posted.  The data that returns after the post (our updated records partial) will replace the current contents of the target-id "recordsDiv".  OnSuccess function "postSuccess" will handle closing the dialog box.  OnFailure function "postFailed" will report that something bad happened.  The last thing to mention is that we changed the post-action from "Create" to "CreateRecord".  I prefer to have unique action names when working with ajax-data returns.  It's just a cleaner approach.

Before we define the new "CreateRecord" post-action, we need to implement our success and failure functions.  Just create them at the bottom of your script-section block in the main "Index" view:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
  // ... other stuff that was already here ...

  function postSuccess() {
    $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog("close");
  }

  function postFailed() {
    alert("Failed to post");  // you can define your own error
  }
</script>
}
```

Lastly, we create the "CreateRecord" post-action, which will process our form and return an updated "records partial" view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateRecord(StockIndexEditViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ... create record here ...
  }

  var records = db.Indexes.ToList(); // or whatever your table name is

  return PartialView("RecordsPartial", records);
}
```

This is repeating some of your existing "Create" action.  We simply process our post data, then we get a new updated list of records, and lastly we return that list of records back to our "RecordsPartial" view, which will be inserted into our "recordsDiv" as we specified in our ajax-options.

Very clean and simple solution.  If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks @Eckert. When I try to close the dialog like you suggest, I get the error "Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'" - which is why I tried initializing it first. I will mess around with your partial view and Ajax helper suggestion and let you know. Appreciate it!

Comment: Problem with that last bit. The CreateRecord post action is sending a type of StockIndexEditViewModel to the partial view, instead of IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.StockIndex>, which of course throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read some of your code.  Just populate the "records" variable with your list of records in the same manner that you would for your initial table.  I'll edit my post to try and make it more clear.  Also, I believe the error you are getting about closing that dialog should resolve itself with the ajax code changes I presented, since the "OnSuccess" function is included in your main Index view.

Comment: Figured as much and re-queried them, and passed them in. Something's still not right. The form in the modal dialog now posts and redirects to /AdminStockIndex/Create (haven't renamed it) - it's only displaying the "RecordsPartial" view - not the entire view. I guess that makes sense as that's what the post method returns...but wasn't the effect I was going for. I double-triple checked the AjaxOptions and they're exactly like you wrote them. It's not replacing the div like expected...just redirecting to it.

Comment: One question... do you have the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax script included in your Index view?  I forgot to mention that this script is required for the ajax component to work properly.  If you don't have this script in your project, you can download the nuget package (Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax).

Comment: No, I hadn't done that. I'm actually trying to avoid using the MVC Ajax helpers, if possible. I like the idea of using jQuery instead and don't mind the extra scripting, as I'm really trying to learn the ins-and-outs of jQuery and Ajax in general. I was able to refresh the table by using the 'close' property in the dialog - that works great now. I'm still trying to find a way to close the dialog on submit, rather than having to click the "x" to close and trigger the table refresh. I'm trying not to use the modal dialog buttons properties and keep the button inside the form, itself.

Comment: I'm going to create another answer that should help with closing the modal

Comment: I got it working! I declared a global variable for the dialog in Index and called close on it from the Ajax post function in the dialog. Sloppy maybe? It works though. Would still like to see your approach.

Answer (score 1):

In your main Index view, rather than calling for your Create view to be inserted into your view, have it initially present at view load, and hide it within a div:

```
<div id="createStockIndexForm">
  @Html.Action("Create", "AdminStockIndex")
</div>
```

In your Index script section, we're creating the dialog OUTSIDE your click event.  We're also turning the "autoOpen" value to false so the div hides at view load.

Index script section:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Create Stock Index',
            modal: true
    });

    $('#createLink').on('click', function () {
        $("#createStockIndexForm").show();
    });
</script>
```

}

Also, when you use the PreventDefault() command, it appears to be interfering with your modal-close command (after some of my own testing).  I suggest that you change your form's "Create" button to type="button" rather than "submit", and then use the ID of the button to handle your ajax-post method.

```
<input type="button" id="createButton" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Add this to your main Index script section at the bottom:

```
$("#createButton").on("click", function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            async: true,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#createStockIndexForm").dialog("close");
                }
                else {
                    $("#result").append("Something went fail.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Make sure to direct your "close" command at the dialog object itself.

Here's a fiddle I created that shows you the gist of how it should be:
http://jsfiddle.net/ch5aLezg/

So to recap on the script stuff, you should have NO SCRIPTS in your "Create" partial.  All the scripts go into the main Index view, as I've detailed in this answer.

Comment: I couldn't get client-side validation working properly, trying it this way. I changed all the "this" references to the form selector (vs the button) but it was a no-go. The form never submits...with or without any data. I had it all working the way I posted it, so I just stuck with that. Thanks again for all your help, anyhow...really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, I was answering too quickly.  The "this" reference in my code was copy-pasted from your code.  I didn't adjust it to meet the criteria. url: '@Url.Action("CreateRecord", "AdminStockIndex")', type: "POST", data: $("form").serialize()

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you for your work on this!!!! A few years later and you guys really helped me out. I translated this to the mvc core style...took me too long, but THANK YOU!